# Backup Linux from Acronis True Image Home?

Tags: linux, backup, acronis-trueimage

I have a a software "Acronis True Image Home"

Is it possible to backup CentOS Linux?

on Windows do I need to create a bootdisk from Acronis and then boot it up on linux server?

I wanted to copy all the files from Server to External USB Hard Drive or via FTP

Answer (score 2):

We need a little detail about what this computer is used for.
If it's for "home use" I use VERY happily remastersys for debian systems:

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/05/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with.html

You can get the same result on your distro with PUNGI:

http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/05/31/remixing-fedora-7/

You can obtain a live cd of your personal computer: wow (and, of course, restore it).

Comment: remastersys only works with debian based systems last i checked... this is a centos, IE redhat based system

Comment: You're right: you have to use pungi. I'm sorry for being inaccurate!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not having luck with Acronis True Image 2011 to recover a Ubuntu 11.04 disk.  I had good success with TI 2009, but it didn't support ext4, so I had to keep the old server on ext3.
Luckily I did a recovery test with this new server before depending on TI 2011.  The backups went well, all the .tib files verified as good, but they won't recover.  TI 2011 keeps losing connection to the .tib disk (and external USB) after failing to restore the partition.  I'd say test TI 2011 *thoroughly* before relying on it to backup Linux and/or look somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using [clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org)  to do that, it is a free software that do the same, you can download it and install on a bootable pen drive or burn a cd disk too boot-up from it.